# get location between certain time swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get the longitude and latitude stored in a database. I'd like to get user location only between 8:00 am - 7:00 pm, regardless of app is in foreground or background. below is my code that so far annotates the location on map, and if it's in background than it logs it in console

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locations = [MKPointAnnotation]()

    lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager! = {
        let manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        return manager
        }()

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {
        // Add another annotation to the map.
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = newLocation.coordinate

        // Also add to our map so we can remove old values later
        locations.append(annotation)

        // Remove values if the array is too big
        while locations.count > 100 {
            let annotationToRemove = locations.first!
            locations.removeAtIndex(0)

            // Also remove from the map
            mapView.removeAnnotation(annotationToRemove)
        }

        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == .Active {
            mapView.showAnnotations(locations, animated: true)
        } else {
            NSLog("App is backgrounded. New location is %@", newLocation)
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't fire up location services at a scheduled time. If you need to know the location while the app is in the background, you need to keep location services running all the time.

But unless your app is proper navigation app that absolutely needs constant, very accurate background location services, you can't keep standard location services running in the background. Nor would you generally want to, because that would kill the battery.

What you could do, though, is keep "significant change" location services running. Even this less accurate, lower battery consumption service will have battery impact, though, but it won't drain the battery anywhere as quickly as standard location services. But it will still adversely impact the battery (because your app will fire up *everytime* the user changed cell towers, not just at particular times), so unless this is a critical feature of the app, you probably don't want to even do this.

This is a long-winded way of saying that you can't easily do what you asked.